# Pygame error: video system not initialized, tried everything

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import LIVELLI
import TUTORIAL


def menu():
    # init che permette tutto
    pygame.init()

    screen_width = 900
    screen_height = 570
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PyGliese -- A Unical Story")


    title = pygame.image.load("sprite/asset/title.png")
    bg_title = pygame.image.load("sprite/asset/unical_bg.png")
    play = pygame.image.load("sprite/button/play.png")
    tutorial = pygame.image.load("sprite/button/tutorial.png")
    esci = pygame.image.load("sprite/button/quit.png")

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(bg_title, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(play, (371, 277))
    screen.blit(tutorial, (371, 364))
    screen.blit(esci, (371, 450))
    screen.blit(title, (202, 45))


    pygame.display.flip()


    running = True

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if 529 >= mouse_pos[0] >= 373 and 346 >= mouse_pos[1] >= 278:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    LIVELLI.lv1()
                    menu()

            if 529 >= mouse_pos[0] >= 373 and mouse_pos[1] <= 426 and mouse_pos[1] >= 369:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    TUTORIAL.tutorial()
                    menu()

            if 373 <= mouse_pos[0] <= 529 >= mouse_pos[1] >= 452:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    running = False


            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False

    pygame.quit()


menu()
```

> ```
> Pygame error : video system not initialized
> ```

I'm working on a game for my university but this error keeps coming out at the `for event in pygame.event.get():`.

I've tried everything but the error keeps popping up anyway, any suggestions?
Sorry for my low-level English, feel free to commit any suggestions for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `pygame.quit()` calls. If you call  `pygame.quit()`, the pygame module will deinitialize; and if you keep using it afterwards, it will throw this error.

So instead of

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
```

just return from the function

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    return
```

and stop calling the `menu` function recursively.

Comment: The error keep popping out anyway...

Comment: Make sure to call `pygame.init()` once at the start of your program, and don't call `pygame.quit()` anywhere.

Comment: Oh thank you, now it works after a little bit of troubleshooting